# Understanding "Verilog default:’1"

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a few questions about what this code does and how it works:

```
x <= '{default:'1} ;
```

1. What is the purpose of the "default" keyword ?
2. What is the purpose of the inner single quote apostrophe before the 1 in this case ?
3. What is the purpose of the inner single quote apostrophe before the { in this case ?

Comment: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697639/what-should-default1-do-in-system-verilog) has a question on this.

Comment: I've read the question on Stackoverflow before posting this one. I'm not asking the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner single quote before the 1 is a numeric literal fill. The `'0`, `'1`, `'z`, and `'x` literals will be extended to fill the width of whatever context they are used in.

The outer single quote before the `{` means that this is an assignment pattern to an array or struct. Assignment patterns require a value for every element of the array or struct, which can be positionally ordered or matched by name/index. When matched by name/index, the `default:` serves as a match to any unspecified element.

This is all explained in section 10.9 Assignment patterns in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)

Comment: In fact your answer states the same as mine, except you use more formal terms. But it's in no way more correct.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:

- its SystemVerilog
- '{} defines a (unnamed) struct
- default:'1 , as the default width is 32bit, is 32x '1' as constant

(if not correct, please correct me)

Comment: This is completely incorrect (other that yes, this is SystemVerilog as it was so tagged)

Comment: dave_59, so what's the correct answer ?

Comment: @shaiko I already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @schnedan - Since we don't know what `x` is, we don't know what it defines. And there is no default width for `'1` in this context. We need to know `x`'s width.

Comment: @dave_59 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179142/systemverilog-structure-initialization-with-default-1 http://www.testbench.in/SV_03_LITERALS.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697639/what-should-default1-do-in-system-verilog ... seems I am right, you not.